# Completing circuits with transistors and arduino

Tags: arduino, control, board

Hello and thanks to anyone who helps.

I am trying to create a test bench for a control board we commonly work on at our business. One control board has 11 pins that a ribbon cable would be connected to. To use the functions on the board we use a wire to short different pin connections on the board. For example: pins 4 to 5 initiate the broil on a certain oven control board.

What I want to do is see if there is a way to do this without using the wire. I want to be able to use an arduino to short the different connections automatically or by a user on a computer.

So I was thinking, could I use a transistor to represent each pin. While being able to still have the function of shorting different pin combinations?

Thanks to anyone who helps. I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Welcome to electronics.stackexchange! Nice question, but it would be good if you provide what kind of signals we are talking about for the pins. If you have data, or measurement signals going trough, the transistor will distort them. The alternative to this is to use mechanical relays. You will need to see if your arduino can give enough current for the switching process though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm fairly uneducated to the electronics world, but I have a basic understanding.

So let's say for example, we have an oven control board and it has 11 separate pins that control the different cycles of the oven... Bake, Broil, Up, Down (Temperature and timer), Clear, etc. Each of these is activated by shorting a connection between a combination of pins. Bake would be 3 and 9. Broil is 4 and 5 and so on.

People have tried transistors before, but when we activate them they aren't being fully activated by the arduino. Relays do work, but it needs to be smaller.

Comment: A schematic would be really useful. For instance, if each pin corresponding to the different signal is always being shorted to a common reference, the problem becomes simpler. However, if they are separate, relays are probably the way to go, as others have mentioned. A diagram or something would be best. Is the control board a standard part? Link?

Comment: Here's an image of a something it would be like: http://tinyurl.com/obq69km

The front panel has buttons on it. When the user presses the buttons it completes the circuit for that function, like bake. So when they press bake it closes the two connections of 1 and 3.

I'm trying to replace the buttons with transistors that can be triggered by an arduino.

Reasoning for this is to have a "virtual" keypad. So we could plug into the control board, then on our PC's, click bake and have it initiate the bake cycle.

Some control boards we get don't have keypads on them. That is the reason for this.

Comment: Please, add all the relevant information you give in the comments to the question itself. The question should stand on its own feet with all the needed info. Also, avoid link to images: you can embed it inside the question using one of the icon in the editing window.

Answer (score 1):

How many connections are required?  Do you need a full cross-point matrix or is there only a few connections needed?  I'm defining "few" as less than 32 relays.

If there are only a few connections needed, I'd probably use relays for this purpose.  They are inexpensive and robust.  You can control pretty much any number of relays from you Arduino by using a simple SPI connection to a bunch of TPIC6595 serial shift registers.  Each shift register will directly drive 8 relays and you simply cascade the shift registers for as many relays as you need.  The SPI interface requires 3 wires from your Arduino.

Comment: No control board goes over 15 pins. We used relays already, and it works, but they're quite bulky. How small can relays get? Basically I'm wondering if transistors can work in place of the relays. We tried simulating the circuit with transistors on 123d circuits, but when we did that, there was resistance in the circuit we were trying to complete. Meaning the transistor wasn't being fully activated.( I think)

One thing I forgot to mention is that we can't have any current flowing into the pins. We only want to be creating a closed circuit with the combination of pins.

Comment: You could use reed relays which come in 14 pin DIP packages.